# Adding custom fields to RadScheduler Appointments

Tags: telerik-scheduler

I have a RadScheduler. It is now displaying  all appointments in the database. I need to display only current loggedin  customer's appointment details. I got a field in my database for the customerId. How i will add it to the Appointments in RadScheduler. 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imo the RadScheduler itself is architectural not the right place to filter your appointments. Rather filter your bound DataSource for the correct appointments. Easy one with Linq, could be something like `datasource.all(appointment => appointment.customerId == context.loginId)`